# How to make an express route do 2 things before sending back a response to the client?

Tags: javascript, express, es6-promise

I'm trying to accomplish various things within an `express route`, in short I have this route `/checkNsguid` where I submit  a form.  I would like the route to do the following:

1. verify if the `nguid` code is a valid one (it exists in the db).
2. if it finds a valid  `nguid code` it copies some fields from the `NGUID table` to the `ModelTable` (it updates the model object)
3. it sends back to the client application the **udpated** model object.

For some reason I'm still getting back the old model obj. I can see that it is updated on the `db` with the valid fields, but `res.send(...)` still sends me the old obj.

I don't know if it's the way I'm using `Promises` , using `next()` or something else I'm missing. If someone could point me on the right direction pls ?

Thanks

```js
/**
 * Check if nguidCode is in the list
 *
 * @return {JSON}
 */
router.post(
  '/checkNguid',
  (req, res, next) => {
    let modelID = req.body.modelID
    let nguid = req.body.nguid

    // 1. Step 1
    // Goes to the CheckNGUID table
    // maps through all the collections until it finds one that matches 
    // the  submitted nguidcode
    // verifies that the code is valid and if so then copies various 
    // fields to the ModelTable via `.updateInfosFromOldDb`

    // After that I don't want anything else to do with that response obj.
    // I want to "pass" control to Step 2 

    nguidCode
      .checkNguid(nguid)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('this is the response inside backend', response)

        response.length === 0
          ? res.status(400).json({ result: 'nok', error: 'Invalid nguidCode' })
          : response.map((el) =>
            // [NOTE]: Updates the model object with the nguid info if found
              modelModel.updateInfosFromOldDb(
                modelID,
                nguid,
                el.rate,
                el.subscribedAt,
              ),
            )
          next()


        // console.log('this is the response inside backend 2', response)
        // res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok', model: response })
        // res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok', model: response })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).json({ result: 'nok', Error: error.toString() })
      })
  },

  // 2. Step 2
  // This is the updated model obj I would like to send back to the client app.

  // [ASK]: I want to send back the updated model Object,
  // However I'm still getting back the old one.
  (req, res) => {
    modelModel.getByID(req.body.modelID).then((response) => {
      console.log('response inside the next()', response)
      res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok', model: response })
    })
  },
)
```

`updateInfosFromOldDb`

```
const updateInfosFromOldDb = (modelID, nguid, rate, subscribedAt) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ModelModel.findOne({ id: modelID }, (err, model) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      model.nguidCode= nguid
      model.rate= rate
      model.subscribedAt =subscribedAt
      //model.payments.push(paymentId);

      model.save((err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(response)
        }
      })
    })
    
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting old response because `next()` being called before `nguidCode.checkNguid` promise resolves i.e. before your database call completes. In order to fix this issue, we need to move `next()` within `then()` block -

```
/**
 * Check if nguidCode is in the list
 *
 * @return {JSON}
 */
router.post(
  '/checkNguid',
  (req, res, next) => {
    let modelID = req.body.modelID
    let nguid = req.body.nguid

    // console.log(req.body, 'req.body in the backend')

    nguidCode
      .checkNguid(nguid)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('this is the response inside backend', response)
        if(response.length === 0) {
          throw new Error('Invalid nguidCode');
        } else {
          // Wrapping list of promises in Promise.all so that then() callback is invoked once all
          // promises are resolved
          return Promise.all(response.map((el) =>
          // [NOTE]: Updates the model object with the nguid info if found
            modelModel.updateInfosFromOldDb(
              modelID,
              nguid,
              el.rate,
              el.subscribedAt,
            ),
          ))
        }
        // console.log('this is the response inside backend 2', response)
        // res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok', model: response })
        // res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok', model: response })
      })
      .then((data) => {
        return next()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return res.status(400).json({ result: 'nok', Error: error.toString() })
      })
    // [NOTE]: This also works I go onto the modelModel.getByID(...)
  },

  // [ASK]: I want to send back the updated model Object,
  // However I'm still getting back the old one.
  (req, res) => {
    modelModel.getByID(req.body.modelID).then((response) => {
      console.log('response inside the next()', response)
      return res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok', model: response })
    })
  },
)
```

Comment: moved the `next()`  as you mentioned but still having the same problem.

Comment: Can you log `response` object before calling `next()`? I am not sure why map has been used there, it will not update response object but will create new array from it. Also, is `updateInfosFromOldDb` an asynchronous function?

Comment: `updateInfosFromOldDb` is an asynchronous function as well. Edited my answer just now with more info

Comment: Ok, map does not wait for async function to complete. Will update answer to handle it.

Comment: thanks that solved the issue,  if I understand correctly. you wrapped everything inside a `Promise.all()` to wait until the promise is completed to then call `next()` ?